# Python C-Type Child Class Name

Tags: python, class, ctypes

How would I go about getting the classname of a Python c-type?

For example:

```
print c_uint32.__name__
>>> c_uint
```

This prints the inherited class of "c_uint", rather than "c_uint32".

I understand that a function can be added to an inherited class to provide the actual name, but since I am using the ctypes module from the standard library, I do not want to make any changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is printing the class name. On your platform the c_uint type is 32 bits, so the ctypes module aliases c_uint to c_uint32.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I followed the alias types and used those and was able to use the `__name__`